# MIPS jump datapath

Tags: mips

I am trying to study for a test and that deals with data path values for load word,SW,ADD,branch equal and Jump. I have everything but the jump. Is this correct?

```
   RegDST dont care
   Branch don't care
   ALUOp1 1
   ALUOp0 don't care
   MemWrite don't care
   MemRead don't care
   ALUSrc don't care
   RegWrite don't care
   MemToReg don't care
```